# Question on Linear Operators

Tags: topological-vector-spaces, unbounded-operators, fa.functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a normed infinite dimensional vector space. Let $L: V \longrightarrow V$ be a bounded linear operator. Moreover assume that $L$ is 'locally nilpotent' that is:
$$ \forall v \in V \quad \exists n \in \mathbf{N}: L^n (v) = 0. $$
Now my question is if the linear operator: 
$$ \exp (L) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{L^n}{n!} $$
is bounded or not.

Comment: Am I missing something? If $L$ has norm $|L|$, then doesn't $\text{exp}(L)$ trivially have norm at most $\exp(|L|)$? 

Comment: Should we assume the series converges?

Comment: Given your tag for the question, don't you want $L$ to be *unbounded*?

Comment: In what sense is the series assumed or supposed to converge? In the operator norm, in the strong topology, etc. ?

Comment: @Mark: if $L$ is locally nilpotent, $\text{exp}(L) v$ is well-defined for any $v$ without making any use of topological structure, and it is not hard to see that it is linear etc. 

Answer (score 2):

$exp(L)$ is bounded, regardless of the local nilpotentcy, since $\|L^n\|\leq \|L\|^n$. On the other hand, if you wanted to ask the question about unbounded $L$ (say, for all $v$ in the domain), then the answer is no.

Comment: If $L$ is a closed operator (but not bounded), then $\exp(L)$ as you define it is also closed.  $L$ can be closed but not bounded since $V$ is not complete...

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$ be the vector space of all sequences which are eventually zero.  Let $L$ be the backwards shift-- this is obviously "locally nilpotent".  Given $V$ the norm
$$ \| (x_n) \| = \sum_n a_n x_n, $$
where $(a_n)$ is some sequence of positive numbers.  Let $e_n$ be the vector which is 1 in the $n$th place, and zero elsewhere.  Then
$$ \exp(L)(e_n) = (\cdots,1/2,1,1,0,\cdots), $$
where the final 1 is in the $n$th place.  So
$$ \|\exp(L)(e_n)\| / \|e_n\| \geq (a_{n-1}+a_n)/a_n = 1 + a_{n-1}/a_n. $$
Hence just choose $(a_n)$ so that $( a_{n-1}/a_n )$ is an unbounded sequence, and then $\exp(L)$ will be unbounded.  E.g. $(a_n)=(1,2,1,3,1,4,1,\cdots)$ will work.

Comment: Of course in your example $L$ is not bounded, so this is not surprising.

Comment: @Jack-- But if $L$ is bounded, then its very very simple to see that $\exp(L)$ is bounded (as Orr explained in his answer)...  So I don't understand your comment?

Comment: Merely that $L$ bounded was assumed in the original post.

Comment: @Jack-- I was following Yemon, and assuming that this was a mistake (given that the question has the trivial answer "yes" otherwise!)